# Vue.js 3 Composition API: Change property value depending on other properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Vue.js 3, Composition API

I have data coming from a legacy server (can't change it!) which looks like this:

```json
{
  "propA": [{"valueA": "x", "valueB": "y"}, {"valueA": "o", "valueB": "p"}],
  "propB": [{"valueL": "a", "valueM": "b"}]
}
```

Each value of each property has an optional field `state` (e.g. `{"valueA": "x", "valueB": "y", "state": "updated"}`), which needs to be set accordingly, depending if the property was `updated` or `deleted`.

Each property has an editor for each of its values (e.g. text input field) which is wrapped in another (reusable) component handling state changes:

- it can reset the value to its initial state
- it can set the values `state` to `deleted`
- it needs to set its `state` to `updated` whenever any property of a value (except `state`!) changes

Each value is passed as `v-model` to the wrapper component.

The wrapper component doesn't know which fields exist, except for `state` (doesn't need to, fields vary a lot), it has buttons to reset the state of the object to its initial value and to set `state` to `deleted`. It should watch for changes to initial data as well and set `updated` or delete `state` accordingly.

On form submit the application sends the data to the server along with the `state` properties.

**What would the best way be to solve this with Vue.js 3?**

I tried watching each value (`{"valueA": "x", "valueB": "y"}`) with a `watch`er function, but then it gets into endless loop on `updateValue` / `deleteValue` in `watch`:

```js
const initialState = lodash.cloneDeep(props.modelValue)

watch(props.modelValue, (new, old) => {
  if (hasInitialStateChanged(new)) {
    updateValue("state", "updated");
  } else {
    deleteValue("state");
  }
});

function updateValue(key, value) {
  emit("update:modelValue", { ...props.modelValue, [key]: value });
}

function deleteValue(key) {
  const o = { ...props.modelValue };
  delete o[key];
  emit("update:modelValue", o);
}

function hasInitialStateChanged(newState) {
  const item = lodash.cloneDeep(newState);
  const originalItem = lodash.cloneDeep(initialItem);
  
  delete item["state"];
  delete originalItem["state"];
  
  return !isEqual(item, originalItem);
}
```

Any ideas? For Angular folks: I used `ngDoChange` and mutated the `state` property accordingly.

Comment: What is hasInitialStateChanged? The problem is that there should be 2 states. You possibly don't want to emit value to a parent until the form is submitted.

Comment: Added the missing function for clarity, it strips the `state` property and compares the initial state with the new state. I can't wait till the form is submitted, some other things depend on the state value as well.

Comment: Perhaps you are designing your solution around the data format from the API, instead of building something that solves your problem first. Say you didn't start with the shape of data that you have but instead you got to pick any format you want. Then your solution will fit the problem at hand and the only place where you need to account for the difference is when you interact with the API. Converting to/from the API model will take some thinking, to map all features out, but afterwards you no longer have the API design bleed in your frontend architecture anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion on Vue forums I found quite an elegant solution, which works fine with the data in its current form.

**Here is a working solution for anyone interested: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)**

```js
//App.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import StatefulEditor from './StatefulEditor.vue'

const o = ref({
  "propA": [{"valueA": "x", "valueB": "y"}, {"valueA": "o", "valueB": "p"}],
  "propB": [{"valueL": "a", "valueM": "b"}]
})

</script>

<template>
  <h1>
    HELLO
  </h1>
  <StatefulEditor v-model="o.propA[index]"
                  v-for="(prop, index) in o.propA"
                  :key="index"
                  >
    <input type="text" v-model="prop.valueA" />
  </StatefulEditor>
  
</template>
```

```js
//StatefulEditor.vue
<template>
    <div>
      <div>
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          v-if="modelValue.state === 'updated'"
          @click="resetItem()"
        >
          RESET
        </button>
        <button
          v-if="modelValue.state === 'deleted'"
          @click="undeleteItem()"
        >
          UNDO
        </button>
        <button
          v-if="(modelValue.state === undefined || modelValue.state === 'created')"
          @click="deleteItem()"
        >
          DELETE
        </button>
        <span>{{modelValue.state}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { watch, computed } from "vue";
import { cloneDeep, isEqual } from "lodash";

const props = defineProps(["modelValue"]);
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

const initialItem = cloneDeep(props.modelValue);
const initialStateChanged = computed(() => hasInitialStateChanged(props.modelValue))
watch(initialStateChanged, (n) => {updateValue("state", n ? "updated" : undefined)})

function resetItem() {
  emit("update:modelValue", { ...initialItem });
}

function deleteItem() {
  updateValue("state", "deleted");
}

function undeleteItem() {
  updateValue("state", undefined);
}

function hasInitialStateChanged(newState) {
  const item = cloneDeep(newState);
  const originalItem = cloneDeep(initialItem);
  
  delete item["state"];
  delete originalItem["state"];
  
  return !isEqual(item, originalItem);
}

function updateValue(key, value) {
  emit("update:modelValue", { ...props.modelValue, [key]: value });
}

function deleteValue(key) {
  const o = { ...props.modelValue };
  delete o[key];
  emit("update:modelValue", o);
}
</script>
```